# Using SUMIF() to find the account balance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this problem to solve using sumif():
[image: exercise image]

Here is the formula I came up with, but it doesn't work:
[image]
Can someone help me point out what's wrong?

Comment: H column should be in Number format to use SUMIF() formula, not Text format. Check the format of the H column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[AMPERSAND](https://exceljet.net/videos/how-to-join-values-with-the-ampersand)** => `& Operator` for the `criteria`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `D7`

```
=SUMIF($G$3:$G$12,C6&C5,$H$3:$H$12)
```

Comment: I tried the exact same formula but it still returned 0:

Comment: =SUMIF($G$3:$G$12;C6&C7;$H$3:$H$12)

Comment: @chi you can see the formula bar as well the cell it shows it returns, please check you data whether it has some non printable characters or spaces.